# How to assign or set an Optional<String> value to a String variable?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to set an `Optional<String>` value returned from a method to a setter method of a model class.

```
public class Person{

    private String address;

    public void setAddress(String Address){
        address = Address;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

}
```

This what i tried out

```
Person person = new Person();    
Optional<String> addr = retrievePersonAddressById(5);
if (addr.isPresent()) {
    person.setAddress(addr.get());
}
```

But i got

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Optional<String>
```

Note:

retrievePersonAddressById() has a return type of `Optional<string>`.

The error is on line

```
person.setAddress(addr.get());
```

I need help please

Comment: is `retrievePersonAddressById` this function returning an `Optional<String>`?

Comment: Yes. I just editted the post. Sorry

Comment: Side note: you can skip the `if` and do `addr.ifPresent(person::setAddress);`.

Comment: The message and line don't add up. Try rebuilding.

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: @shmosel, what do you mean by the message and line don't add up? Please explain further.

Comment: The error you're describing is impossible under normal circumstances. Either you're leaving out information or the build is in a bad state. Are you sure the `Person` class is defined exactly as you've shown?

Comment: Thank you so much Shmosel your comment was really helpful. I have figured out the cause the error of which I'm so ashamed to disclose because it's a blunder.

Comment: Well now I'm curious...

Answer (score 8):

If the error is happening on this line:

```
Optional<String> addr = retrievePersonAddressById(5);
```

change it to `Optional<String> addr = Optional.of(retrievePersonAddressById(5));`

Comment: And write `if (true) {` instead of `if (addr.isPresent()) {`, yeeeeah!

Comment: i just edited the post to clarify things. Sorry for the initial post.

Comment: @Jamal, yea but I am getting the error message on that line

Comment: I'm still getting the error after applying this solution. Any suggestions?